# Producing the next available filename for a pattern (02-output.log etc)

Tags: shell-script, scripting, filenames

I can use `mktemp(1)` within a shell script to make a temporary file in a directory with a suitable suffix & prefix.

Is there a command that, given a pattern (e.g. `NN-output.log`) will look for `01-output.log`, and if that exists return `02-output.log` (or next available number)? I want a command to "get the next sequentially available filename" without having to write that myself in a script.

I know I could use `date -Iseconds` or similar to get unique, increasing, filenames, but is there anything that'll produce more simplier increasing filenames?

I know it's probably easy to write such a programme, but before I do it myself, I want to see if someone's already done it.

**Update** Someone asks "how would the script know the pattern?" I'm suggesting that much like mktemp, one would give the pattern to the programme. e.g. "Give me the next file named like output-XX.log" and the programme would look at the X's and fill in `01`, look for that file, etc.

Comment: How would the script know the pattern? Consider file names like `file.1.txt` `01file`, `file1`, `file01`, `file.one`, `fileA`, `filea`, `Afile` etc. It's easy to do for a specific file name style but the general solution is not trivial. That said, yes, getting unique file names _is_ trivial, it just requires a simple shell loop. If that's what you're after, let me know and I can post one.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a shell function that's usable with at least ksh and bash. As the comment says, it's hard-coded to expect an input pattern from this particular Question; that is, of the format "XX" (exactly two X's) followed by something -- not (something)-XX as one part of the question implies.

The script uses parameter expansion to strip off the leading XX's to save for later recombination with the increasing `n` index. It then loops from 1 to 99, zero-pads the number if it needs it, then looks for the non-existence `[ ! -f ... ]` of such a file. If it does not exist, then it prints that filename and returns successfully (`return 0`). If it exits the loop without finding an available file, it prints a message to stderr (`>&2`), prints *nothing* to stdout, and returns with an unsuccessful return code (`return 1`).

```
# hard-coded to expect an input pattern of XX(something)
function rmktemp {
  pattern=$1
  suffix=${pattern#XX}
  n=1
  while [ $n -lt 100 ]
  do
    if [ $n -lt 10 ]
    then
      n="0${n}"
    fi
    tfile="${n}${suffix}"
    if [ ! -f "$tfile" ]
    then
      printf "%s\n" "$tfile"
      return 0
    fi
    n=$((n+1))
  done
  if [ $n -eq 100 ]
  then
    echo Could not find an unused file >&2
    return 1
  fi
}
```

Use it like:

```
LOG=$(rmktemp XX-output.log)
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo stuff > "$LOG"
```